# Eclipse synchronization ".classpath" differs from repository

Tags: java

***Eclipse** acts as **".classpath"** edited*, and puts it in synchronization tab.

When I try to commit that into the repository on SubVersioN, eclipse gives multiple errors. I use jdk 1.6 and maven with Java. When not committing that .classpath thing, there is not any single error. I can commit my other class files succesfully.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

**How can I tell Eclipse that, ".classpath" is not edited or changed?**

Comment: Firstly, how do you know that file hasn't changed? That's an Eclipse file that will be altered whenever you make certain changes to your projects. Secondly, please tell us what errors you see - otherwise we can't possibly help you.

Comment: Secondly - are you sure you want to version-control that file? If you are using a build system such as Maven or Ant, you probably don't want to be version-controlling Eclipse files, like `.project`, `.classpath` or the `.settings` folder.

Comment: Duncan is right: I always recommend to not put IDE specific files into version control. This way, each developer can choose whatever IDE he wants to use (if any at all). You also could work from command line (which CI systems do, for example). Using Maven and the M2E plugin in Eclipse for example is very easy: Checkout the project and afterwards configure it to be a Maven project. No need to have the meta files under version control.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Duncan, file size is the same. there is no change. I do not want to version control that file. It is not needed. How can I make that .classpath file stay "out of" version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

Eclipse handles all project's meta files itself. There are several actions that could lead to changes in the `.classpath` or even in the `.project` file. Most likely changes in the POM.

Errors when trying to commit such changes are most likely due to having a lower local SVN revision than the repository or due to conflicts. For both, do not use the synchronization perspective, but first do an SVN update (rightclick your project -> Team -> Update). If there is a conflict, you will be notified and must solve it. If there is no conflict, you should be able to commit changes, now.

For the future:

I always recommend to not put IDE specific files into version control. This way, each developer can choose whatever IDE he wants to use (if any at all). You also could work from command line (which CI systems do, for example). Using Maven and the M2E plugin in Eclipse is very easy: Checkout the project and afterwards configure it to be a Maven project. No need to have the Eclipse meta files under version control.

If you want to change it right now, do the following:

1. Remove the Eclipse meta files from the project folder. Commit that
   change. I recommend to directly operate on the SVN repository (using
   a repo browser, for example) or to checkout to another place, do the
   changes there, and commit.
2. Do an SVN update your project in Eclipse. This will remove the meta
   files. Update your project and then convert it again to a Maven
   project (see above).
3. Last step: Ignore the meta files, so that they will not be committed
   again. This can be done with Eclipse itself or with the svn:ignore
   property (we do the latter).

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you say there are meta files that I did not touch there too. I will try your advise.